# How can I preview a securely downloaded file (.XLSX, .PPT, etc) in-browser for users?

Tags: .net, angular, download

I am building an Angular app where users are able to download specific documents (.XLSX, .PPT, .PDF, etc.) from the server.  Users must be authenticated, and document access is restricted by role.  No issues here!

PDFs are simple - the app asynchronously downloads the file from the server and opens in a new tab using the built-in browser preview.  Great!

The Office documents are the issue though.  **.XLSX and .PPT files just immediately download to the users' download folder, but we would ideally like to just view them first in the browser before downloading the full file to the download folder.**

I have looked into using the Microsoft / Google document previews, but those will not work for this case, as we can't expose docs to the public web / send to an offsite 3rd party service.

Comment: Sure, to clarify I **am** downloading from the server, however the PDFs are simply rendered in the browser - they are not downloaded to the user's download folder.  I would like to do the same with office files.  The file is going to be downloaded as a blob either way, but it's a matter of allowing the user to view said file in the browser without having to open Excel / Word, etc.

Comment: If you have access to the server-side code, you could implement a viewer control that is able to display the document that is accessible to a cleared user. As an example, the LEADTOOLS JavaScript/HTML5 [Document Viewer](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer) Library supports PDF and MS Office format documents and has a customizable interface. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)